# How to inherit another class when a class already extend a class and an Interface

Tags: delphi, oop, class, inheritance, interface

I work with Delphi 2006 and I have a complex class named `TMyClassTest` that have many methods
Some of those methods create nonvisual components and assign event handlers of those components and run methods of those components.

Also I have two classes that implement the same interface like below:

```
TMyClass1 = class(Class1, Interface1)
   ... //procedures from the Interface1
   procedure MyClass1Proc1;
 end;

TMyClass2 = class(Class2, Interface1)
   ... //procedures from the Interface1
   procedure MyClass2Proc1;
   procedure MyClass2Proc2
 end;
```

Now I need that TMyClass1 and TMyClass2 to 'inherit' the TMyClassTest, too. 
Much more ... Interface1 must contain (beyond its methods) all the methods from the MyClassTest.
How can I avoid to implement (like copy/paste) on both clases (TMyClass1 and TMyClass2) all the procedures from TMyClassTest ?
I don't want to keep the same code on three separate places.

Based on Arioch's comments I created a solution like:
(see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Implementing_Interfaces_by_Delegation_.28Win32_only.29)

```
    type
      IMyInterface = interface
        procedure P1;
        procedure P2;
      end;
      TMyImplClass = class
        procedure P1;
        procedure P2;
      end;
      TMyClass1 = class(Class1, IMyInterface)
        FMyImplClass: TMyImplClass;
        property MyImplClass: TMyImplClass read FMyImplClass implements IMyInterface;
        procedure IMyInterface.P1 = MyP1;
        procedure MyP1;
      end;
      TMyClass2 = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
        FMyImplClass: TMyImplClass;
        property MyImplClass: TMyImplClass read FMyImplClass implements IMyInterface;
        procedure P3;
        procedure P4;
      end;
    procedure TMyImplClass.P1;
         // ...
    procedure TMyImplClass.P2;
         // ...
    procedure TMyClass1.MyP1;
         // ...
    procedure TMyClass2.P3;
         // ...
    procedure TMyClass2.P4;
         // ...
    var
      MyClass: TMyClass1;
      MyInterface: IMyInterface;
    begin
      MyClass := TMyClass1.Create;
      MyClass.FMyImplClass := TMyImplClass.Create; //Error !!!! FMyImplClass is a read only    property !!!
      MyInterface := MyClass;
      MyInterface.P1;   // calls TMyClass1.MyP1;
      MyInterface.P2;   // calls TImplClass.P2;
    end;
```

Because I have an error at `MyClass.FMyImplClass := TMyImplClass.Create;` I tried to create `FMyImplClass` declaring constructor from `TMyClass1` and `TMyClass2` but don't work ok. 
Is there some other method to create `FMyImplClass` ?

Now I tried a solution that seem to work ok. Can there happen some hidden efects?

```
    type
      IMyInterface = interface
        procedure P1;
        procedure P2;
        procedure CreateFMyImplClass;
      end;
      TMyImplClass = class
        procedure P1;
        procedure P2;
      end;
      TMyClass1 = class(Class1, IMyInterface)
        FMyImplClass: TMyImplClass;
        property MyImplClass: TMyImplClass read FMyImplClass implements IMyInterface;
        procedure IMyInterface.P1 = MyP1;
        procedure MyP1;
        procedure CreateFMyImplClass;
      end;
      TMyClass2 = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
        FMyImplClass: TMyImplClass;
        property MyImplClass: TMyImplClass read FMyImplClass implements IMyInterface;
        procedure P3;
        procedure P4;
        procedure CreateFMyImplClass;
      end;
    procedure TMyImplClass.P1;
         // ...
    procedure TMyImplClass.P2;
         // ...
    procedure TMyClass1.MyP1;
         // ...
    procedure TMyClass1.CreateFMyImplClass;
    begin
     FMyImplClass := TMyImplClass.Create;
    end;
    procedure TMyClass2.P3;
         // ...
    procedure TMyClass2.P4;
         // ...
    procedure TMyClass2.CreateFMyImplClass;
    begin
     FMyImplClass := TMyImplClass.Create;
    end;
    var
      MyInterface: IMyInterface;
    begin
      if WantRemote then
         MyInterface := TMyClass1.Create
      else
         MyInterface := TMyClass2.Create;
      MyInterface.CreateFMyImplClass;   // create FMyImplClass ;
      MyInterface.P2;   // calls TImplClass.P2;
    end;
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276173/how-to-implement-multiple-inheritance-in-delphi

Comment: 1) make Class1 and Class2 inherit from TMYClassTest or 2) make TmyClassX no more implementing Interface1 directly, but instead add them a field of TMyClassTest and *delegate* their Interface1 to this field

Comment: You are out of luck. Delphi doesn't do multiple inheritance. On the other hand, inheritance is a grossly over-used and mis-used tool. Take this as a sign that composition is the way to go.

Comment: Class1 is not my class and can't change anything on it.

Comment: TMyClass1 is not my class and can't change anything on it. TMyClass2 is my class and look like: class(TInterfacedObject, Interface1). I created TMyClass2 because I have a variabile like var x: Interface1; I need to use on some situations x := TMyClass1.Create and on other situations x := TMyClass2.Create;

Comment: for moment I deleted TMyClassTest and I implemented the code in TMyClass1 and TMyClass2 but is hard to keep sincronised the code. Now I use TMyClass2 instead of TMyClassTest.

Comment: In MyClass1 I can change/add only the methods from Interface1

Comment: David, sorry for my english. What mean: composition is the way to go ?

Comment: Is the functionality of TInterfacedObject all you need to add?

Comment: TMyClass1 = class(class1,Interface1) belong to a remote interface system for client server apps. I can add how many functionalities I want in Interface1 and I can implement those functionalities on TMyClass1. I have a variable like X := TMyClass1.Create; that I use when the client is connected to the server. The same variable X is used like X := TMyClass2.Create; when the client is not connected to the server. I created TMyClass2 = class(TInterfaceObject, Interface1); because X must have the Interface1 type (the declaration is like X: Interface1;).

Comment: I used copy/paste for methods from TMyClassTest and I implemented them on the TMyClass1 and TMyClass2 (and of course in the Interface1 I declared those methods). My app work ok but because I want to extend this app I need a solution, if is possible, to avoid the duplicate code from TMyClass1 and TMyClass2. TMyClassTest was deleted and I use the object X (with the methods that I added in the Interface1) instead of the object created with the old class TMyClassTest.

Comment: I tried to put the old code in a separate unit and reuse it on the TMyClass1 and TMyClass2 classes but was not possible because some procedures are events.

Comment: Arioch, can you point me to an example of your ideea ?

Comment: I still don't really understand your needs

Comment: @sorin doing Google for "delphi interface delegation" shows this as top link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483680 I think you'd better move that new common functions into some Interface0 type, and make Interface1 a child of Interface0. Then you make some TMyClasssBaseCommonTrait class, implementing Interface0, and two subclasssec TMyClass1InternalEngine(TMyClasssBaseCommonTrait) and TMyClass2InternalEngine(TMyClasssBaseCommonTrait) implementing (in different, TMyClassX-specific ways, the rest of Interface1(Interface0) API /// Delphi does not have Scala-like traits or Py-like mixins

Comment: @David, I have two classes that implement the same interface. A part of the interface is implemented identically in both classes. I want to find a way that not duplicate the code that is implemented identically on both classes

Comment: @Arioch, Yes I found on google a way to Implementing Interfaces by Delegation to a Class-Type Property. Seem to be ok, I will test now (example is for XE3 and I have D2006) but there seem to be a limitation i.e. win32 only (not a problem for the moment, maybe in the future). the link is [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Implementing_Interfaces_by_Delegation_.28Win32_only.29)

Comment: @sorin i believe that means "it does not apply to Delphi.Net" but since .Net is long not supported that effectively means nothing.

Comment: I edited my problem description

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719900/safe-way-in-delphi-for-a-form-to-distribute-interface-objects-tied-to-its-lifeti) and the use of TAggregateObject. I think it is as close as you can get in Delphi.

Comment: I edited again my problem with a solution that seem to work ok. Can exists hide efects? also I'm interested about why in the first solution was not possible to run: MyClass.FMyImplClass := TMyImplClass.Create; (error because FMyImplClass is a read only property but is an example from Embracadero)?

Comment: I thank all of you for this help. Special thanks to Arioch that got me sent to correct solution. I think that now we should close this discussion but I don't know exactly how. Can I receive help again ?

Comment: *Interface = interface* u meant *IMYInterface = interface* ?

Comment: if u consider discussion complete - i summed my suggestions into one answer that u can accept. OTOH i think many participants in this discussion suggested the same in other words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi does not have Scala-like traits or Python-like mixins, nor it support multiple inheritance a la C++.

If you cannot make `Class1` and `Class2` inherit from `TMyClassTest`, then perhaps you have to rely on *interface delegation*: make `TMyClassX` no more implementing `Interface1` directly, but instead add them a field of `TMyClassTest` and delegate their `Interface1` to this field.

I think you'd better

1. move those new common functions into some `Interface0` type
2. make `Interface1` inherited from `Interface0`
3. make some `TMyClassesBaseCommonTrait` class, implementing `Interface0`
4. make two subclasses `TMyClass1InternalEngine(TMyClassesBaseCommonTrait)` and `TMyClass2InternalEngine(TMyClassesBaseCommonTrait)` implementing (in different, `TMyClassX`-specific ways, the rest of `Interface1(Interface0)` API
5. have `TMyClassX` classes internal private field of `TMyClass2InternalEngine` type doign real implemntation

Google for "delphi interface delegation" shows this as top link: [Delphi: How delegate interface implementation to child object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483680)